# How to access docker web app through ssh?

Tags: docker, ssh

I use my personal computer (PC) to connect to a remote machine (RM) via SSH.

The RM runs some docker containers to host a test website.
From the RM, it is easy to access the website in browser simply by going on the docker ip address.

But how do i access the docker ip address (which runs on the RM) from my PC?

Comment: `docker exec` le the docker way, you car install and configure SSH, but.it is not the docker way

Comment: @user2915097 - no you didn't understand me. i modified the description. hope it makes more sense now

Comment: It's not yet clear what are you asking for. Are you looking way to 1) query your web page through command line, or 2) enter inside running docker container, or 3) something else?

Answer (score 0):

To access to your web app from a web browser you have to use the `-p` option. You need to map your port (and ip if you want to), for example if you want to access to a PhpMyAdmin use

```
docker run -itd -p 80:80 <your_web_php>
```

And then you can access to it with the ip address of your server and the port you've selected. If it was a Tomcat you should do

```
docker run -itd -p 8080:8080 <tomcat>
```

Remember that you can choose the access port you want, the first one, the second is the port used by your app.